# Calculating trend per customer in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I use the following function to calculate the trend (slope)in the outflow amount per customer. However, I get the identical number as a result for the whole dataset. Is there a way to iterate over each customer id in the dataset and obtain individual trends per customer? Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np

def trendline(data, order=1):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(data.index.values, list(data), order)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)
outflow = payment['AMOUNT'] 
month = payment['MONTH']

df_ = pd.DataFrame({'month': month, 'outflow': outflow})
slope_outflow = trendline(df_['outflow'])
slope_outflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a bit of sample data to put in?

As a possible solution, in these situations I usually use a groupby.

```
for c in df_.groupby('CUSTOMER'):
    trendline(c)
```

Comment: I have  customer_id, month, outflow columns and each customer has one outflow per month. I want to find the outflow trend for each customer id. I tried your suggestion, but still getting the same trend for every customer

Comment: @gunel, without data to simulate the behavior, its too difficult to try to diagnore, unfortunately.